# Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.Mathematics.pdb: Copying the file failed - unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

i tried to import package that is google unity plug ( admob ) when i add it in unity it show this error after added

```
Library\ScriptAssemblies\Unity.Mathematics.pdb: Copying the file failed: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Well, on the surface it looks like either an issue with permissions (unable to read file) or locking (some other process is preventing access to it).  The question might benefit from a few more details, e.g. operating system, versions, etc.

Comment: yes i fix this problem by add admob version 6.0 to my unity 2020